# MySQL left join with 3 tables not yielding results

Tags: mysql

I need to get data from 3 tables. However, I can only get correct results as long as there are 2 tables. As soon as I join the 3rd table, I get null results. The query that works is:

```
select a.first_name,a.last_name,a.email, a.birthdate,b.mobile_phone
from REGISTRATION a 
left join TRIPS b on a.trip_id=b.trip_id 
where a.trip_id=9 and  registration_status='Active'
```

However, as soon as I use following query to get data from 3rd table, I get null results:

```
select a.first_name,a.last_name,a.email, a.birthdate,b.mobile_phone,d.country_name
from REGISTRATION a 
left join TRIPS b 
on a.trip_id=b.trip_id and registration_status='Active'
left join DESTINATION_COUNTRY d 
on b.destination_country_id=d.destination_country_id
where a.trip_id=9
```

Please advice me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: There's nothing wrong here.

Comment: Define "get null results".  As in you get zero results returned?  Or do you get results with null values?

Comment: These are fundamentally different queries because you've changed a global predicate "registration_status='Active'" into a join predicate.  So that could certainly explain getting null values.  It would not explain getting no results returned.

Comment: @BrianRudolph. When I check if($result == NULL){ echo "null result";}, I get "null result" printed. It seems the $result variable has nothing in it and hence I think nothing gets returned by the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should remove this from join "and registration_status='Active'" and move it to where clause :

```
select a.first_name,a.last_name,a.email, a.birthdate,b.mobile_phone,d.country_name
from REGISTRATION a 
left join TRIPS b 
on a.trip_id=b.trip_id 
left join DESTINATION_COUNTRY d 
on b.destination_country_id=d.destination_country_id
where a.trip_id=9 and registration_status='Active'
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. Could you explain the difference between the placement of WHERE clause with and registration_status='Active' here? Thanks.

Comment: when you put this condition "and  registration_status='Active'" in left join like you did, you will get null results because you get all left rows whatever the join condition, but when make your left join, you will get all results according to your left join then you apply the "and  registration_status='Active'" condition to all results (result in left join) as a one table.